# unable to validate output of this recursive program

Tags: python, recursion

We have this recursive python program:

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

As per my understanding the output of this program should have been:

```
1,3,5,7,9,11
```

But the actual output is:

```
1,3,6,10,15,21
```

Can someone explain the reasoning behind it?
This is my understanding program will start as

```
k as 6, then 6 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(6-1) 
now k is 5, then 5 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(5-1) 
now k is 4, then 4 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(4-1) 
now k is 5, then 3 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(3-1) 
now k is 2, then 2 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(2-1) 
now k is 1, then 1 > 0 then system will call tri_recusrion(1-1) 
now k is 0, then 0 !> 0 condition will break

now function will start to return in reverse order:
tri_recusrion(1-1) in this case k is 1; k + (1-1) prints 1
tri_recusrion(2-1) in this case k is 2; k + (2-1) prints 3
tri_recusrion(3-1) in this case k is 3; k + (3-1) prints 5
tri_recusrion(4-1) in this case k is 4; k + (4-1) prints 7
tri_recusrion(5-1) in this case k is 5; k + (5-1) prints 9
tri_recusrion(6-1) in this case k is 6; k + (6-1) prints 11
```

Comment: @quamrana: I am unable to understand why program is generating this (actual) output. need explanation for this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first explain what this function does:

`k` is the argument of the function, the base condition is when `k` is 0, result is 0 and nothing is printed, function just returns 0

If `k` is greater than 0, the program calculates tri_recursion(`k-1`), adds it to the `k` and prints it then returns it

If we call the function with argument `k=6`, it will call the same function with `k=5`, then it does the same with `k=4` ... and finally call itself with `k=0` and program will stop calling itself. After that point calculated result will be carried to the call one level before to finalize that call.

Thus, the steps to execute right after program reach `k=0` are as follows.

Since `k=0` returns `0`, result of `k=1` becomes `k + 0` => `1 + 0`, prints `1` and returns it

Since `k=1` returns `1`, result of `k=2` becomes `k + 1` => `2 + 1`, prints `3` and returns it

Since `k=2` returns `3`, result of `k=3` becomes `k + 3` => `3 + 3`, prints `6` and returns it

Since `k=3` returns `6`, result of `k=4` becomes `k + 6` => `4 + 6`, prints `10` and returns it

Since `k=4` returns `10`, result of `k=5` becomes `k + 10` => `5 + 10`, prints `15` and returns it

Since `k=5` returns `15`, result of `k=6` becomes `k + 15` => `6 + 15`, prints `21` and returns it

Comment: why are you using `k + 0 => 1 + 0` in my question I am subtracting. I do not follow your answer.

Comment: that `0` indicates `tri_recursion(k - 1)`, which is the result of one lower-level recursion result.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the function is called by itself, it adds the current value of `k` to `result`. The current list that you're printing is `1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, ...`, which is also `1, 3, 6, 10, ...`. To fix the error, write `result = 1` and `result = 2 + tri_recursion(k - 1)` instead of `result = 0` and `result = k + ...`, respectively.

Comment: The question does not ask for corrections, it needs explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the visualization of the  call graph with args and return values in each recursive call in your code.

[image]

You can click through a step by step progression on this excellent in-browser [python recursion visualizer](https://www.recursionvisualizer.com/?function_definition=def%20tri_recursion%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%20%3E%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20k%20%2B%20tri_recursion%28k%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result&function_call=tri_recursion%286%29).